# Adding unit tests for an existing objective c + swift project

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, unit-testing

I have an existing iOs project which I would like to add a unit test target to. The classes I'd like to test are both in objective c and swift.

I've managed to create a test target which allows me to test swift only code by adding the implementation swift files to the test target.

However, as soon as I import or use a class that imports objective c code, I run into Linker issues when building the test target:

`...
Symbols not found for architecture x86_64`

I've tried adding the objectivec mm files to my target which gets my passed the linker error, but I then get an `unresolved identifier` error for the class I'm importing.

I'm using xcode 9 and swift 3.

edit: I think this may have something to do with the fact the swift bridging header is not available in the test target, however I'm not sure how to add it.

Comment: which symbols are not found? how have you managed to solve problems with mm files?

Comment: The symbols that are not found are the ones from the objective c class which is imported

Answer (score 0):

Your test project is a separate target and should have all files it relies upon to be tested linked separately. So first of all click one of the `.m` files it's missing and check if the test project is also included in the targets. If this is the case there might be a problem with the bridging header your test project uses. Figure out which one it uses from the build settings of your target and see if it includes the same files as your main project.